# Draw on custom widget after it's drawing

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a custom widget, which inherits QWidget. It has own paintEvent and I cannot change it. So I want to use such a widget in my dialog object, but I need to draw some graphics on it after it draws its own graphics (that widget draws video frames on it, an I need to draw some lines over it). Can I draw every time after the paintEvent of that widget? I used installEventFilter and caught the event wuth type Qt::Paint, but I canoont see anything I've drown. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can override your custom widgets paint event and draw there. Here is an example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/painting-basicdrawing.html

Comment: No no, It has it's own implementation of paintEvent, but I cant change it, becouse rendering video frames implemented there, and it's not my code, i use it as dynamic library

Comment: @mmmaaak: it's != its. I fixed this in your posts, but you keep writing in comments, too. Please understand the difference. It is tiresome to read that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can derive from the custom widget class, reimplement `paintEvent`, and call the inherited `paintEvent` first, then do your drawing.
2. You can install an event filter on the widget and do the same: call the widget's `paintEvent` first, then do your drawing.
3. Hide the other widget. Create your own widget, and call the other widget's `render` method in your widget's `paintEvent`, then do your drawing. Since the other widget is presumably rendering video frames that change periodically over time, you might need to use a timer to `update()` your widget.

In neither case are you modifying the 3rd party custom widget.

In order to call other widget's protected `paintEvent` you need to be using a `QWidget`, even if just a dummy, invisible one.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simple code sample that draw inside a custom widget.  It draws a blue rectangle inside of a QPushButton.

The method used is exactly what has been described in option 1 by @Kuba

So, you inherit from the custom widget class where you want to draw in, reimplement `paintEvent`, and call the inherited `paintEvent` first and the do your drawing.

Hope this helps

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>

// inherit from the class over which you want to draw
class DrawOverButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DrawOverButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QPushButton(text, parent)
    {
        // enlarge the button so there is some space to draw in
        setStyleSheet("QPushButton {min-height: 60px; "
            "min-width: 120px; margin: 5px;}");
    }

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
        // call the base class paint event method
        // this will draw the base class content
        QPushButton::paintEvent(event);

        // draw a blue border inside the button
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor("#3cf"), 4));
        const int distance = 20;
        painter.drawRoundedRect(QRect(distance, distance,
            width() - 2 * distance, height() - 2 * distance),
            10, 10);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    DrawOverButton *button = new DrawOverButton("Button");
    button->show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```