# paintEvent in QTableView derived class: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

Tags: qt, qtableview, qpainter, qt5.4

As a follow up of [Qt load indicator by animated image (aka preloader) or alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636864/qt-load-indicator-by-animated-image-aka-preloader-or-alternative) I try to paint inside a `QTableView`. But when I initialize the `QPainter` I get the following warnings.

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

Here is the code (SO answer, [with a button it seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19020683/356726)):

```
    void CDerivedFromQTableView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QTableView::paintEvent(event); // draw original content
        QPainter p(this); // Problem: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
        const QPixmap pm(QPixmap::grabWidget(this->m_loadIndicator));
        QPoint middle = this->geometry().center();
        int x = middle.x() - pm.width() / 2;
        int y = middle.y() - pm.height() / 2;
        p.drawPixmap(QPoint(x, y), pm); // draw load indicator inside QTableView 
    }
```

I am surprised creating the `QPainter`fails, so why is that. What am I doing wrong?

The simplified version still gives the warning

```
        QPainter p(this);
        QTableView::paintEvent(event);
        return;
```

Warning (of course) gone when I comment out `QPainter`, so it really seems to be the root cause, but why?

Comment: You should probably call `QPainter painter(this);` instead of `QPainter(this);`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As `QTableView` is a subclass of `QAbstractScrollArea` you should open `QPainter` on its viewport:

```
void CDerivedFromQTableView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QTableView::paintEvent(event); // draw original content

    QPainter p(this->viewport());
    p.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
}
```

[The docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#paintEvent) say it:

> This event handler can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive paint
>   events (passed in event), for the viewport() widget.
>
> Note: If you open a painter, make sure to open it on the viewport().