# Warning QPainter inside paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qchartview

I tried to draw some more information in QChartView so I re-implement paintEvent

```
  virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QChartView::paintEvent(event);
    OmenChart *mchr = dynamic_cast<OmenChart *>(this->chart());
    if(mchr == nullptr)
        return;
    QPainter painter(this);

    const int labelOffset = 2 + 2;
    painter.setFont(this->font());
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black));
    QFontMetrics fm(painter.font());


    const OmenScatterSeries *omnSr = mchr->serie();
    QVector<QPointF> points = omnSr->pointsVector();
    QStringList labels = omnSr->pointLabels();

    for (int i(0); i < labels.count(); i++) {
        QString pointLabel = labels[i];

        // Position text in relation to the point
        int pointLabelWidth = fm.width(pointLabel);
        QPointF position(points.at(i));
        position.setX(position.x() - pointLabelWidth / 2);
        position.setY(position.y() - labelOffset);
        painter.drawText(position, pointLabel);
    }
}
```

and I am taking these errors

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::font: Painter not active
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
```

Any ideas on this ? I had also used painter.begin and end but I took the same errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not draw on your subclass of *QChartView*, but instead on its viewport.

[QChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchartview.html) is derived from [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html), which in turn is derived from [QAbstractScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655856/5366641) (as well as the cited there [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#paintEvent)) you should use the viewport as a paint device for your *QPainter*, not the widget itself.

So, instead of

```
QPainter painter(this);
```

write

`QPainter painter(viewport());`

The same could be seen in the [source of QGraphicsView](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.cpp.html#_ZN13QGraphicsView10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent), i.e.:

```
// Set up the painter
QPainter painter(viewport());
```

Comment: Yes it seams to work now!

Comment: I am glad to hear that.

Comment: I 've thought I did it already :D

Comment: @chatzich, Thank you! :)